# error TS2339: Property 'hide' does not exist on type 'RegisterComponent'

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using angular 9 and I got an error, here's the code

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex.xs="100">
      <mat-label>Password</mat-label>
      <input matInput type="text" placeholder="Password" formControlName="password"
        id="password" [type]="hide ? 'password' : 'text'">
      <mat-error *ngIf="registerForm.hasError('required', 'password')">
       atleast 1 small,1 Capital, 1 digit, 1 special char and length 6-10 characters.</mat-error>
      <mat-error *ngIf="registerForm.hasError('required', 'password')">password is required</mat-error>
      <mat-error *ngIf="registerForm.hasError('password', 'minlength')">password length should be 6 
      </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Please add a short description of what you are trying to acheive.

Comment: Most likely you have not declared "hide" variable in your component. Please share your component code as well for more clarity.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have a material password input type you forgot some little things :
If we look to the exemple in material documentation you can see :

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>Enter your password</mat-label>
    <input matInput [type]="hide ? 'password' : 'text'">
    <button mat-icon-button matSuffix (click)="hide = !hide" [attr.aria-label]="'Hide password'" [attr.aria-pressed]="hide">
    <mat-icon>{{hide ? 'visibility_off' : 'visibility'}}</mat-icon>
    </button>
  </mat-form-field>
```

you forgot to add the toggle button to switch between text and password type :

```
  <button mat-icon-button matSuffix (click)="hide = !hide" [attr.aria-label]="'Hide password'" [attr.aria-pressed]="hide">
    <mat-icon>{{hide ? 'visibility_off' : 'visibility'}}</mat-icon>
 </button>
```

And in the .ts file you need to declare a variable named hide like this:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

/** @title Form field with prefix & suffix */
@Component({
  selector: 'form-field-prefix-suffix-example',
  templateUrl: 'form-field-prefix-suffix-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['form-field-prefix-suffix-example.css'],
})
export class FormFieldPrefixSuffixExample {
  hide = true;
}
```

see the angular material doc [here Form field with prefix & suffix](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview)
and here the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ggbmzf?file=src/app/form-field-prefix-suffix-example.html)